# Remount page after navigating to same route - sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

When im using svelte-kits routing system, I can create dynamics pages using `[page].svelte` for example, that will be rendered when I'm calling `localhost:3000/foo`. However when I'm navigating from `localhost:3000/foo` to `localhost:3000/bar`, the `onMount()` function is not called (I guess for performance reasons).

I can work around this issue by wrapping all relevant stuff in a `{#key ... }` expression, but is there any way to "remount" the page?

Thenks for helping me out :)

Comment: Any particular reason why you would want to remount? If you have actions that you want to trigger when `page` changes, you can put all these actions inside a function and call that function when `page` updates with a reactive statement that is dependent on `page`, for example: `$: doRefresh(page)`.

Comment: Maybe since I'm coming from other libraries, I'm still used to this convention, but your suggestion is also an elegant way.
As @Bob Fanger mentioned, rarely I had some issues with third party libraries (p5js) where a `canvas` element was not fully removed, leading to performance issues. There it seemed easier to just fully 'remount' the page.

Comment: That's a fair assessment, and for these situations `{#key}` would indeed be the right choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `onMount` is not called, but the props *are* being updated.
This allows the new data to flow to the existing dom elements and the browser doesn't have to regenerate an entirely new page/component.

If there is state calculated based on these props, make sure that those are inside reactive statements and not just inside the onMount.

In some situation (with third-party code) it's more convenient to remount the component, and in those cases you'll use the `{#key}` block you mentioned.